# Get Windows Phone 8 to use the network connected interface

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I'm writing a test app for Windows Phone 8 and testing in the emulator. I want to create a UDP socket and determine the local socket end point used. The issue I've got is that the emulator has two network interfaces only one of which has external network connectivity. By default the non-connected interface gets used. How can I ensure that the correct adapter is used when I create the socket?

```
Socket m_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
m_socket.SetNetworkPreference(NetworkSelectionCharacteristics.NonCellular);

SocketAsyncEventArgs receiveArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
receiveArgs.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
receiveArgs.SetBuffer(new Byte[2048], 0, 2048);
receiveArgs.Completed += SocketRead_Completed;

// If I bind to the specific IP address of the connected adapter it will work.
//m_socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.1.1.7"), 0));

// if I leave it up to WP8 the wrong adapter gets used.
m_socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0));

m_socket.ReceiveAsync(receiveArgs);
```